# Doubts about Cordova 3.6 webviews, events & updating application

Tags: android, cordova

I am using PhoneGap / Cordova 3.6 to build my first Android Application. I have successfully created a static application however I still have a few conceptual doubts, I am listing them below it will be great if someone can help me out with these.

1. PhoneGap events:   Do I require installing any plug-in to access or make use of these events? 
   Ref: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton
2. Embedding WebViews: How important is this for creating an application using PhoneGap. Does it improve the performance of the application in any way? 
   Ref: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_hybrid_webviews_index.md.html#Embedding%20WebViews
3. How can I change the version of Android Application created using PhoneGap: I read that the application version requires to be changed in order to update the application. To do so I went into my /*application folder*/platforms/android/ in AndroidManifest.xml & edited the android:versionCode & android:versionName to a higher number. However after doing so when I re-build the app using "cordova build" in CLI; the default version number is restored. So am I doing the right thing by updating the version number? or is there any other method to do so using CLI

EDIT: Hi Kerri, as per your advise I changed the version identifier in the config.xml. However when I download the apk file on my phone & run it; it asks me to re-install the entire application & not the updates.

Thanks for your time.

Thanks,
Utpal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. If you look at the top of that page, it does list a few events added by other plugins, but `back button` and the like are built in.
2. Ignore this. It's only useful if you are trying to embed a bit of PhoneGap into a native app. For example, you might have an existing native app that you want to add new functionality to, but you want to do that portion in PhoenGap. You can embed PG in your native app and get the benefits of both worlds.
3. Check out `config.xml` in your project root -- there's a version identifier in there.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I may bother you for the 3rd point again just incase it does not work for me.

Comment: Hi Kerri, as per your advise I changed the version identifier in the config.xml. However when I download the apk file on my phone & run it; it asks me to re-install the entire application & not the updates.

Comment: When I download the apk file with a newer version and run it shows me the following message:

The application that you are installing will replace another application. All previous user data will be saved. 

Does this mean it's updating and not overriding the previous version? 

Thanks